# ssh + gpm support on android

Tags: android, ssh

There are many SSH clients for Android, but none I tried so far supports forwarding touch events to apps linked with libgpm. Does there exist such as SSH client for Android?

Price is irrelevant, they are all cheap. Touch events are the only requirement.

Comment: Any other specific features that app *must* have (e.g. supporting SSH keys)? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software? Also, while waiting for recommendations, be welcome to peek into my list of Android [SSH Clients](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_387).

Comment: Price is irrelevant, they are all cheap. Touch events are the only requirement. If you tried to use a TUI app under some linux terminal emulator, you'll see they all support clicks and such and forward them.